# Send and receive dynamic arrays in MPI

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, dynamic-arrays

I have a big problem with send and (or) receiving dynamic arrays with MPI. Below is just a part of my code, but it should be enough to see what i am doing wrong. Please help me, i'm after all night of searching solution. 
I get sth like this:
*** glibc detected**  ./mv2.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000da2a70   glibc detected  **./mv2.out: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000000da2a50 ***

When I replace dynamic arrays with static everything works perfect.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MASTER 0
#define FROM_MASTER 1
#define FROM_WORKER 2

double **alloc_2d_array(int rows, int cols) {
    int i;
    double *data = (double *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double));
    double **array= (double **)malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int degree,
    numtasks,
    taskid,
    numworkers,
    source,
    dest,
    mtype,
    rows,
    offset,
    averow,
    extra,
    i, j, k, rc;

    MPI_Status status;

    double **a, *b, *c;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
    if (numtasks < 2 )
    {
        printf("Aby rozpoczac obliczenia rownolegle potrzeba co najmniej 2 procesow.\n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
        exit(1);
    }
    numworkers = numtasks-1; 

    if (taskid == MASTER)
    {
        printf("Podaj stopien macierzy: \n");
        scanf ("%d", &degree);
        printf("Obecnie dostepnych jest %d procesow do dyspozycji mastera.\n", numtasks);

        FILE *file;

        file = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
        if(file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Nie mozna otworzyc pliku!\n");
            MPI_Finalize();
            exit(0);
        }

        a = alloc_2d_array(degree, degree);
        b = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);
        c = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);

        printf("Tworzenie macierzy z pliku\n");
        for(i = 0; i < degree; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < degree; j++)
                fscanf(file, "%lf", &a[i][j]);

        for(i = 0; i < degree; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < degree; j++)
            {
                printf("%f", a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("Tworzenie wektora z pliku\n");
        for(i = 0; i < degree; i++)
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &b[i]);

        for(i = 0; i < degree; i++)
        {
            printf("%f\n", b[i]);
        }

        fclose(file);

        averow = degree / numworkers;
        extra = degree % numworkers;
        offset = 0;
        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        for (dest = 1; dest <= numworkers; dest++)
        {
            rows = (dest <= extra) ? (averow + 1) : averow;
            printf("Wysylanie %d wierszy do procesu nr %d, z offset'em = %d\n", rows, dest, offset);
            MPI_Send(&degree, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], rows * degree, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&b, degree, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            offset = offset + rows;
        }

        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++)
        {
            source = i;
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&c[offset], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("Otrzymalem wyniki od procesu nr %d\n", source);
        }

        printf("***\n");
        printf("Wektor wynikowy:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < degree; i++)
        {
            printf("\n%6.2f", c[i]);
        }
        printf("\n***\n");
        printf ("KONIEC\n");
    }


    if (taskid > MASTER)
    {
        b = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);
        c = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);

        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        MPI_Recv(&degree, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&a, rows * degree, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        MPI_Recv(&b, degree, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            c[i] = 0.0;
            for (j = 0; j < degree; j++)
                c[i] += a[i][j] * b[j];
        }
        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&c, rows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The shortest version to reproduce error:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MASTER 0
#define FROM_MASTER 1
#define FROM_WORKER 2

double **alloc_2d_array(int rows, int cols) {
    int i;
    double *data = (double *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double));
    double **array= (double **)malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int degree,
    taskid,
    source,
    dest,
    mtype,
    rows,
    offset,
    i, j;

    MPI_Status status;

    double **a, *b, *c;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);

    if (taskid == MASTER)
    {
        FILE *file;

        file = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");

        a = alloc_2d_array(degree, degree);
        b = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);
        c = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);

        for(i = 0; i < degree; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < degree; j++)
                fscanf(file, "%lf", &a[i][j]);      

        for(i = 0; i < degree; i++)
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &b[i]);

        fclose(file);

        offset = 0;
        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        MPI_Send(&degree, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], rows * degree, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&b, degree, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }


    if (taskid > MASTER)
    {
        a = alloc_2d_array(degree, degree);
        b = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);
        c = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * degree);

        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        MPI_Recv(&degree, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        // v HERE IS THE PROBLEM v
        MPI_Recv(&a, rows * degree, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&b, degree, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

EDIT: Version without sending from worker to master works correctly, but when I add responsing application suspends.
In the link below you can find example with static arrays. When I replace them with dynamic ones, application doesn't work properly.
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/C/mpi_mm.c

Comment: What's the problem? Can you reduce your code down to the bare minimum to recreate it?

Comment: I added complete source code. When I replace dynamic arrays with static everything works perfect.

Comment: It would make for a much clearer question if you could write a minimal example to reproduce your problem. For example, just allocate one array and send/receive it.

Comment: Why do you think it is the problem? Which output do you get and which output do you expect?

Comment: I got sth like this:
*** glibc detected *** ./mv2.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000da2a70 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./mv2.out: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000000da2a50 ***

Comment: Edit your question to add this the and possibly other important information.

Comment: Then compile your code with `-g` and do some debugging. At the moment, the only way anyone can help you is by visual inspection of your source code, which is pretty much the worst kind of debugging. It seems to rely on a file named `matrix.txt` in order to run, which we don't have. Like I said before, it would be helpful to you and to us if you cut the code down to the minimum number of lines that can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Having to be a bit psychic here as you haven't posted a complete program that can be run and tested (please do this in future, for instance here you haven't include all the #includes and #defines required, and also you don't supply an input file). However from what I can see your problems in the recv are two fold. Firstly you haven't allocated any memory for a on the "worker" processes. Secondly what you specified as the starting address for the recv of a is incorrect. Here is a cut down version of your code which does what I think you want (but again I'm guessing a bit). Also please note C is very much my second language so please check what I have done. Anyway here it is:

```
ian@ian-pc:~/test$ cat mpi.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "mpi.h"

#define FROM_MASTER 1
#define FROM_WORKER 2

#define MASTER 0

double **alloc_2d_array(int rows, int cols) {
  int i;
  double *data = (double *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double));
  double **array= (double **)malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

  return array;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int degree, numtasks, taskid, numworkers, dest, mtype, rows, offset, averow, extra, i, j;

  MPI_Status status;

  double **a;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
  if (numtasks < 2 )
    {
      printf("Aby rozpoczac obliczenia rownolegle potrzeba co najmniej 2 procesow.\n");
      MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);
      exit(1);
    }
  numworkers = numtasks-1; 

  if (taskid == MASTER)
    {
      printf("Podaj stopien macierzy: \n");
      scanf ("%d", &degree);
      printf("Obecnie dostepnych jest %d procesow do dyspozycji mastera.\n", numtasks);

      a = alloc_2d_array(degree, degree);

      printf("Tworzenie macierzy z pliku\n");
      for(i = 0; i < degree; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < degree; j++)
      a[ i ][ j ] = i + 10 * j;

      printf( "Initial\n" );
      for(i = 0; i < degree; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < degree; j++) 
      printf("%f ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
      }

      averow = degree / numworkers;
      extra = degree % numworkers;
      offset = 0;
      mtype = FROM_MASTER;
      for (dest = 1; dest <= numworkers; dest++)
        {
      rows = (dest <= extra) ? (averow + 1) : averow;
      MPI_Send(&degree, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&(a[offset][0]), rows * degree, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      offset = offset + rows;
        }

    }


  /* Attempt to order output, not gauranteed to work */
  MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD );

  if (taskid > MASTER)
    {

      mtype = FROM_MASTER;
      MPI_Recv(&degree, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      a = alloc_2d_array( rows, degree);
      /* MPI_Recv(&a, rows * degree, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  */
      MPI_Recv(&(a[0][0]), rows * degree, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 

      printf( "Final from %d\n", taskid );
      for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    printf( "%d ", taskid );
    for(j = 0; j < degree; j++)
      printf("%f ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
      }
    }

  MPI_Finalize();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
ian@ian-pc:~/test$ mpicc -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O mpi.c
In file included from mpi.c:5:0:
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:220:9: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’ [-Wlong-long]
mpi.c: In function ‘main’:
mpi.c:45:13: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
ian@ian-pc:~/test$ mpirun -np 3 ./a.out
Podaj stopien macierzy: 
2
Obecnie dostepnych jest 3 procesow do dyspozycji mastera.
Tworzenie macierzy z pliku
Initial
0.000000 10.000000 
1.000000 11.000000 
Final from 1
1 0.000000 10.000000 
Final from 2
2 1.000000 11.000000 
ian@ian-pc:~/test$ mpirun -np 3 ./a.out
Podaj stopien macierzy: 
4
Final from 1
1 0.000000 10.000000 20.000000 30.000000 
1 1.000000 11.000000 21.000000 31.000000 
Final from 2
2 2.000000 12.000000 22.000000 32.000000 
2 3.000000 13.000000 23.000000 33.000000 
Obecnie dostepnych jest 3 procesow do dyspozycji mastera.
Tworzenie macierzy z pliku
Initial
0.000000 10.000000 20.000000 30.000000 
1.000000 11.000000 21.000000 31.000000 
2.000000 12.000000 22.000000 32.000000 
3.000000 13.000000 23.000000 33.000000 
ian@ian-pc:~/test$ mpirun -np 3 ./a.out
Podaj stopien macierzy: 
5
Final from 2
2 3.000000 13.000000 23.000000 33.000000 43.000000 
2 4.000000 14.000000 24.000000 34.000000 44.000000 
Obecnie dostepnych jest 3 procesow do dyspozycji mastera.
Tworzenie macierzy z pliku
Initial
0.000000 10.000000 20.000000 30.000000 40.000000 
1.000000 11.000000 21.000000 31.000000 41.000000 
2.000000 12.000000 22.000000 32.000000 42.000000 
3.000000 13.000000 23.000000 33.000000 43.000000 
4.000000 14.000000 24.000000 34.000000 44.000000 
Final from 1
1 0.000000 10.000000 20.000000 30.000000 40.000000 
1 1.000000 11.000000 21.000000 31.000000 41.000000 
1 2.000000 12.000000 22.000000 32.000000 42.000000 
ian@ian-pc:~/test$
```

However also learn about MPI_Bcast, it would be useful here ...

Comment: Thank you very very much! You save me! I really appreciate what you've done to me.

Comment: I am really sorry, but this didn't resolve my problem. When I send from master and receive in worker there is no problem, but when I try to send from worker to master it's blocked. What should I do?

Comment: First show the code that isn't working. An try to avoid an input file, what we need is an example we can test ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The way you allocate your array dynamically seems strange. Usually you do it like that:

```
double **alloc_2d_array(int rows, int cols) {
    int i;
    double **array= (double **)malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = (double *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double));
    return array;
}
```

And then deallocation would also happen in two steps:

```
void free_2d_array(double*** arrayPtr){
  double **array = *arrayPtr;
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++) free(array[i]);
  free(array);
}
```

UPDATE: Assuming that it's more efficient to do in the way it was originally suggested, the allocation should be like this:

```
double **alloc_2d_array(int rows, int cols) {
    int i;
    double *data = (double *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double));
    double **array= (double **)malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = data + cols*i;

    return array;
}
```

In this case, the deallocation is also easy: calling `free` for both arrays.

Comment: It is better to allocate it in one step and then set the row pointers to have a contiguous array. It is much easier to work with it in MPI.

Comment: Yes, I have no time to correct it, there is a nice solution in another question here in an answer by Jonathan Dursi, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Yes that is more or less that, +1 from me. Just you probably wanted `cols*i`.

Comment: Isn't `data + cols*i` just a pointer arithmetic version of what the OP has got? Also, please don't cast your `malloc`s in C.

Comment: Perhaps so but it doesn't change the behaviour so it can't be the solution to the problem. I don't see how this is an answer.

Comment: You are right Tom, I didn't study the question carefully enough and concluded there is some error to fast. Then I just quickly check the allocation here is at least correct.